# Python - Trying to use the value of a name from one module in a different module

Tags: python

I'm a newbie at programming. Going to fire that one straight out there. Now I'm going to list three modules of code:

```
def GCD(x,y):
#gives the Greatest Common Divisor of two values.
while y != 0:
    r = x
    while r >= y: #these two lines are used to 
        r -= y    #calculate remainder of x/y
    x = y
    y = r
print x
```

This is the original program I wrote, based on Euclidean Algorithm for GCD. It functions correctly. I now want to remove the two commented lines above and replace it with a call to a further module I made, which calculates the remainder:

Remainder Calculator

```
def xy(x, y):
#Gives the remainder of the division of x by y. Outputs as r.
   while x >= y:
       x -= y
   r = x
```

This program also functions correctly. 
I want to use the value of the name 'r' in my edited program. I have attempted to do this below, but it causes problems:

```
def GCD(x,y):
import remainder
#gives the Greatest Common Divisor of two values.
while y != 0:
    remainder.xy(x,y)
    from remainder import r #here is the problem. This line is my attempt at 
                            #importing the value of r from the remainder calculating
                            #module into this module. This line is incorrect. 
    x = y
    y = r #Python cannot find 'r'. I want to use the value for 'r' from the execution
          #of the remainder calculating module. Attempts to find how have been
          #unsuccessful.
print x
```

I need to find out how to use the calculated value of 'r' from my xy module in my second GCD module. I have tried using

```
global r
```

in my module though I have had no success. I'm not sure if I am interpreting the function of 'global' correctly.

I would appreciate your help.

Jet Holt

Comment: Why not just have your remainder function return `r` instead of trying to set it?

Comment: `global` gives the name a module-level scope, not an absolutely global scope. So yes, you are misunderstanding its function. Return `r` instead of setting it. You shouldn't use `global` if you can help it.

Comment: Thanks, Return did what I wanted. As I mentioned, I am a complete newbie and wasn't aware of the "send data back" purpose of return. Jet Holt.

Comment: @JetHolt No worries. Now you know - try to apply that mindset to your Python code from here on out. A useful tip: the names of the arguments in the function do not have to be the same as the names of variables you pass in, and, in fact, they have nothing to do with each other. Furthermore, when you pass a variable in as an argument, you make a copy of its `id`, so it's not actually call-by-reference and the internal version has local-to-the-function scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
from remainder import xy
def GCD(x,y): 
    #gives the Greatest Common Divisor of two values.
    while y != 0:
        r = xy(x,y)
        x = y
        y = r 
    print x
```

and

```
def xy(x, y):
#Gives the remainder of the division of x by y. Outputs as r.
   while x >= y:
       x -= y
   return x
```

Comment: Why do you have `from remainder import r` in there? What is `r`? If it's actually in there it will shadow the previous value of `r` and if it's not in there you'll get an `ImportError`.

Comment: +1^ I did a quick copy and paste job and missed that when I was skimming the code. I'll take it out, thanks for the catch